# Trying to find out how many times numbers come out in a series

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with number series and I want to count how many times a particular number shows up (i.e. 4)
Attached is a screenprint 
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8wzi.jpg)
I looked for samples but no one seems to be trying to do the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Lenny

Comment: more details.. how many times it shows up in each cell? or total?

Comment: You can use `COUNTIF()`

Comment: For doing it once, you may use Data -> Text to Columns, and then COUNTIF (as @TimWilliams said). For a repetitive task, coding this in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is in A1:A4, and you want to count the number of times "1" occurs, you would use:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4, "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I put random numbers between 0 and 100 in a1 through e5, using `=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)`.

In another column, starting in G6, I put the numbers 1 through 100. Then in H5 I placed the formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$5,G6)` and filled down.

It kept a count of how many times each number occurred. And every time I entered a new number, the array of numbers would update and the counts would change.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your data is all in one column, `A1:A24` all two digit numbers (with leading zeroes if required) and with numbers not repeated within individual cells, in which case you can use `COUNTIF` **with a wildcard**, e.g. to count "04" try

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A$24,"*04*")`

or if you want the criteria as a cell value put 4 or 21 or whatever in C2 and use

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A$24,"*"&TEXT(C2,"00")&"*")`